# Copy a struct to a struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, store

Hey guys I need some help. I'm trying to store a SCar struct into an array of Scar inside the SOwner structure, for each  different SOwner, though I'm getting this error:

> Incompatible types when assigning to type 'Scar'  from type 'struct SCar *'

Here's some code :

```
typedef struct {
char name[40];
SCar cars [100];
} SOwner;

typedef struct {
char color[40];
char brand[12];
} SCar;

SOwner *ownerPTR;
SCar *carPtr

void function(){
for(i=0; i<10 ; i++){
    (ownerPtr)->cars[i] = (carPtr+i);   // Problem here <<<--
}
```

Is there any simple way to make this work out? Thanks

Comment: Just `ownerPtr->cars[i] = carPtr[i];`

Comment: In general, if code isn't working, pare it down to the simplest example that doesn't work, which in this case would be something like `int n; int *p; n=p;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must dereference the pointer on the right hand side to generate a value of type `SCar`.

Like so:

```
ownerPtr->cars[i] = carPtr[i];
```

or

```
ownerPtr->cars[i] = *(carPtr + i);
```

But the latter is just a more complicated way to write the former, so just use indexing.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define an array of pointers

```
typedef struct {
    char name[40];
    SCar * cars [100];
} SOwner;
```

Comment: It's not necessary to touch the struct definition unless OP wants to avoid the implicit copying of `SCar`s.